# How to retrieve temporary AWS credentials from Amazon using IAM role associated with the EC2 instance(in java)?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I created IAM role associated with the EC2 instance on AMAZON and as I understood from the amazon docs I can retrieve temp AWS credentials and do some stuff with that.I read that the EC2 metadata api(which is used internally by InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider) is only available for calls from within the instance, not from the outside world.
What this means? How can I get secure communication with AWS when develop app on local tomcat server?

Comment: By AWS Credentials means which credentials are you looking for?

Comment: Well, that credentials will be used to access to dynamo db and s3 buckets I believe.Do not want to use hard-coded AWS access key and secret key in my app, but create IAM role with policy and make a communication with AWS services.

Comment: Well this is a very broad question to answer regarding the secure connection to AWS resources depends on how you plan to design the app. About your first question the temp credentials call are available only from the EC2 instance which has a role for example to access S3 bucket. So when you run this command "curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/s3access" from the terminal of the EC2 instance you will get temp credentials to use. But this will happen only from with the EC2 instance and not outside that instance.

Comment: Here is some guide you can follow http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html#instance-metadata-security-credentials

Comment: For java you can follow http://docs.aws.amazon.com/java-sdk/latest/developer-guide/java-dg-roles.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use the *The default provider chain and EC2 instance profiles*. In your case, since you've already added the role to your instance, and considering you are using the Java SDK, you need to call:

```
InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider mInstanceProfileCredentialsProvider = new InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider();
AWSCredentials credentials = mInstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.getCredentials();
```

Or, if you are using a specific service, such as AWS S3, you can directly call:

```
AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain());
```

For more information: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/java-sdk/latest/developer-guide/java-dg-roles.html

And just a reminder: you should **NEVER** leave your Access Key and Key Secret in your code.

Comment: we used this  InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider in our code , and we are getting "Resources should be closed" sonar issue , I'm confused how can i close it within the method which actually returns the just the AWSCredentialsProvider ?

Answer (score 3):

It appears that your situation is:

- You have an application running on a computer that is *not* an Amazon EC2 instance
- You wish to give that application the ability to make API calls to AWS services

In this situation, it is **not appropriate to use an IAM role**.

Instead, you will need to provide your application with a set of valid AWS credentials (Access Key + Secret Key). This can be done by creating an **IAM User**, copying the credentials provided and placing them in your application's configuration.

When making an API call from an application that uses an AWS SDK, the SDK will automatically look in various location for valid credentials. In the case of Java, the [DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.html) that looks for credentials in this order:

- **Environment Variables** - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY (RECOMMENDED since they are recognized by all the AWS SDKs and CLI except for .NET), or AWS_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_SECRET_KEY (only recognized by Java SDK)
- **Java System Properties** - aws.accessKeyId and aws.secretKey
- **Credential profiles file** at the default location (~/.aws/credentials) shared by all AWS SDKs and the AWS CLI
- Credentials delivered through the **Amazon EC2 container service** if AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI" environment variable is set and security manager has permission to access the variable,
- **Instance profile credentials** delivered through the Amazon EC2 metadata service

Therefore, store the credentials in one of the first three options.

Comment: Way to cover the actual question (even though it was written very poorly).